# How to download html page with Rest api response

Tags: java, html, spring-boot

I have a html file in spring boot located at src/main/resources/templates/MyFile.html.

I tried with Thymeleaf and tried sending response in html page. But its not working. Below is the sample code.

My **RestContreoller** method is

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/display", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getEmployee(@ModelAttribute String employee)
    {
            ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
            mav.setViewName("MyFile");

            mav.addObject("employeeList", "employee");
            return mav;
    }
```

And my **HTML** page is

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Display Employee Details</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

When I invoke a get api call from Swing application, it redirects to my spring boot application. From spring boot application I want to send response in a html page which is located inside spring boot application at src/main/resources/templates/MyFile.html. This html page should be downloaded at client's end.

Comment: Do you want to download **HTML** page or want to show value in html page?

Comment: @AvijitBarua I want my response values inside html tags and download html page at client side

Comment: What are you getting now ?

Comment: When I tried above scenario its not working at all as per my requirement. I tried several other ways. Content is getting displayed in browser instead of downloading.

Comment: First of all , please let me know your requirements. Why do you want to download **HTML**  page? Is it for any reason?

Comment: When user clicks on a button from Swing application then a html page should be downloaded.

Comment: If you download **HTML** you won't get dynamic value putted in html page from controller

Answer (score 0):

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/display", produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE,
    method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> saveEmployee(String employee)
    {
        String content =  "<html><body><h1>Hi there</h1></body></html>";

        String htmlFileName = "MyHtmlFile.html";

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE));
        headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        headers.set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + htmlFileName);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(content, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```